# I can retrieve the information from parse, also I can print that array, but when I try to put those array element in tableviewcell nothing shows up

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform

I can retrieve the information from parse, also I can print that array, but when I try to put those array element in table view cell nothing shows up
the array.count also return 4 
I don't know why table cell is empty

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class friendsViewController: UITableViewController {


    var user = PFUser.currentUser()

    var friends = [String]()
     var profileFile = [PFFile]()


     var height : CGFloat = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        //friends
        var query = PFQuery(className:"Requests")
        //query.orderByDescending("requestBy")
        query.whereKeyExists("requestTo")
        query.whereKey("requestBy", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                // The find succeeded.
                println("Friends recieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
                // Do something with the found objects
                if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                    for object in objects {
                        println(object)
                        self.friends.append(object["requestTo"] as! String)
                        println(self.friends)
                    }

                } else {
                    // Log details of the failure
                    println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
                }

                println(self.friends.count)
            }
        }
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return friends.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return (height/7)
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let myCell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("friendCell") as! friendsTableViewCell

        myCell1.friendLabel.text = friends[indexPath.row]

        return myCell1

    }
```

}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When your block is finished, please call your table to reload data.
Fixed it...

```
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                if error == nil {
                    // The find succeeded.
                    println("Friends recieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
                    // Do something with the found objects
                    if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                        for object in objects {
                            println(object)
                            self.friends.append(object["requestTo"] as! String)
                            println(self.friends)
                        }

                    } else {
                        // Log details of the failure
                        println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
                    }

                    println(self.friends.count)

                    yourTableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

`friends` is populared *after* the table view loads. After you've received your data, on the main thread, call `tableView.reloadData()`.